# How to retrieve textbox data in php

Tags: php, html

I want to retrieve the data from a textbox which I created. Please take look at my code and help me.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['ok']))
{
$a=1;
$n=$_GET['n'];
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
    echo '<form action="exa.php" method="get">';
echo '<input type="text" name="kal'.$a.'"/> <br/>'; 
echo '</form>';
$a++;} $a=1;
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
{
    $txtnm="kal".$a;
    $kal=$_GET['$txtnm'];
    echo $kal;  
    $a++;
}
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="exa.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="n"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="OK" name="ok"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I am getting an error saying `'undefined index $txtnm'`

Comment: PHP without whitespace is torture.

Comment: `$kal=$_GET['$txtnm'];` - Remove the quotation marks.

Comment: That is actually a notice..Ignore that.

Comment: All things are on the same page, so you will get that warning. Use it like if(isset($_GET[$txtnm])) { $kal = $_GET[$txtnm]; echo $kal }. You should first check if there is $_GET[$txtnm] element or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i am getting error that undefined index $txtnm ...

```
$kal=$_GET[$txtnm];
```

remove the single quotes, you are treating it as constant if you put those single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this

```
echo 'Input '.$a.'<input type="text" name="kal[]"/> <br/>';
```

and after submitting form the kal array like

```
print_r($_REQUEST['kal']);
```

And why you are using get method,without specific need dont use get method while submitting the textarea data,because some of special characters causes your redirect

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quote from `$kal=$_GET['$txtnm']` . It should be

```
   $kal=$_GET[$txtnm];
```